# Can get I get rid of FileNotFoundException / MissingMethodException when using NUnit and Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: mono, nunit, json.net

In my Mono application I am using `NUnit` for unit-testing and `Newtonsoft.Json` for serialization. However, as soon as I add a new type using `JObject` (from `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`), the `NUnit` doesn't run tests anymore and reports with `FileNotFoundException` or `MissingMethodException` (depending on the type - see below). I am completely puzzled on how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Here are some screenshots. Normal execution:

[image: normal execution - no reference to <code>JObject</code>]

Execution with error:

[image: execution with error - class derived from <code>JObject</code>]

MissingMethodException is raised when when creating a delegate using `JObject`:

[image: [execution with error - delegate using <code>JObject</code> is added]

Creating a local variable of `JObject` type works fine.

**UPDATE:** All three examples work fine in Xamarin Studio 4.0.9 on Windows with Mono 2.10.9 build 0. In the screenshots, I've used Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 and MonoDevelop 3.1.0.

Comment: what version of Mono and Monodevelop is this?

Comment: @knocte: Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1, MonoDevelop 3.1.0

Comment: try Mono 3.x and MonoDevelop 4.1.x

Comment: @knocte: I'm just trying now. Please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682879/how-to-force-monodevelop-build-to-use-alternative-mono-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by knocte, I've updated Mono to 3.0.12 and MonoDevelop to 4.0.10. Everything works now. It must have been a bug in the previous version.