# How to force MonoDevelop build to use alternative Mono installation?

Tags: build, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to build MonoDevelop 4.0.9 on Ubuntu 12.04, which needs Mono 2.10.9 or later to build. Since Ubuntu only provides Mono 2.10.8, I've built Mono 2.10.9 from sources and installed into /opt/mono-2.11. How do I force ./configure to use Mono 2.10.9 from /opt/mono-2.11/bin instead of /usr/bin?

I've tried updating `$PATH`, but it didn't help:

```
/tmp/monodevelop [(monodevelop-4.0.9)]$ PATH=/opt/mono-2.11/bin:$PATH
/tmp/monodevelop [(monodevelop-4.0.9)]$ ./configure

Configuring package: main
-------------------------
Configuration options:
Running aclocal  ...
Running automake --foreign  ...
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-compile-warnings --prefix=/usr/local ...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-compile-warnings
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for mono... /opt/mono-2.11/bin/mono
checking for gmcs... /opt/mono-2.11/bin/gmcs
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: error: You need mono 2.10.9 or newer
/tmp/monodevelop [(monodevelop-4.0.9)]$
```

**UPDATE:** I've just tried running an existing MonoDevelop installation using new Mono:

```
~$ PATH=/opt/mono-2.10.9/bin:$PATH monodevelop

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Addins, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Mono.Addins, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-latest-1345013906/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelopMain.cs:16
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Addins, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Mono.Addins, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-latest-1345013906/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelopMain.cs:16
Missing method get_IsInitialized in assembly /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.Ide.dll, type Mono.Addins.AddinManager
```

Does this mean that my Mono installation is not complete? Do I need to build these missing assemblies somehow?

**UPDATE:** I've tried using [Parallel Mono Environments](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments) and created the ~/mono-dev-env (I didn't change GNOME_PREFIX, because I don't think I have it installed). However I still get an error when running MonoDevelop:

```
/tmp/mono-2.10.9$ . mono-dev-env
[mono] /tmp/mono-2.10.9 @ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.9 (tarball Wed Jul 17 12:46:30 CEST 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
[mono] /tmp/mono-2.10.9 @ monodevelop

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Addins, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Mono.Addins, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-latest-1345013906/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelopMain.cs:16
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Addins, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Mono.Addins, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-latest-1345013906/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelopMain.cs:16
Missing method get_IsInitialized in assembly /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.Ide.dll, type Mono.Addins.AddinManager
```

Comment: 1st: why are you building mono 2.11 instead of mono 3.x? 2nd: please use a parallel mono environment: http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments

Comment: @knocte: i use 2.11 because I found an automatic build script for it... but I will probably build 2.10.9 instead as it's stable. Will look into parallel environments - meanwhile you can suggest it as an answer.

Comment: scripts that build mono are so simple that is not worth "grabbing" them from anywhere; it would be weird that they work for a version and don't for another; Mono 3.x is pretty stable even if it is claimed to be beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure a Mono app runs within the custom version of Mono that you have built, you should use a [parallel mono environment](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments).

Comment: Why do I need to install Gnome into /opt/gnome to build Mono? That sounds like a lot of extra work with its additional issues. Or is it automatically installed already? Where can I find it on my system? Path /opt/gnome doesn't exist.

Comment: but what should i write into GNOME_PREFIX?

Comment: what it says in the wiki page, it doesn't matter that it doesn't exist